# ORA-00904: "CUSTID": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, ora-00904

```
create table Customer(
    Custid number (20) primary key,
    Custname char(20),
    phno number(10),
    pan varchar2(20),
    DOB date
    );

create table HomeLoan(
    HLoanid number (20) primary key,
    Amount number(10),
    foreign key(Custid) references Customer(Custid)
    );
    
create table VehicleLoan(
    VLoanid number (20) primary key,
    Amount number(10),
    foreign key(Custid) references Customer(Custid)
    );
```

When executing the above create table queries I received a error as

> ORA-00904: “CUSTID”: invalid identifier

Comment: You forgot the `custid` column in the last 2 tables.

Answer (score 2):

You forget to create column `Custid` in `HomeLoan` and `VehicleLoan` tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    Custid number(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    Custname CHAR(20),
    phno number(10),
    pan varchar2(20),
    DOB DATE
    );

CREATE TABLE HomeLoan (
    HLoanid number(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    Amount number(10),
    Custid number(20),
    CONSTRAINT fk_customer FOREIGN KEY (Custid) REFERENCES Customer(Custid)
    );

CREATE TABLE VehicleLoan (
    VLoanid number(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    Amount number(10),
    Custid number(20),
    CONSTRAINT fk_customer FOREIGN KEY (Custid) REFERENCES Customer(Custid)
    );
```